# getReference() vs. getChild()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering what the difference between  `database.getReference("foo/bar/123")` and `database.getReference("foo").child("bar").child("123")` is?

I'm assuming that the later one will load the complete "foo" object whereas `database.getReference("foo/bar/123")` just loads the "123" object?

Is my assumption correct or what is the correct / most efficient way to only load data of "123"?

Answer (score 3):

The two are equivalent.  You can inspect this manually this by printing the [toString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#toString()) format for both References.

References are cheap - there's nothing inefficient about either solution.  Neither one has yet loaded any data.  A Reference is just a pointer to a location in the database.

Comment: what's the best when we use keepSync(true) ?

Answer (score 2):

It should not make a difference, a reference is not actually accessed when instantiated. This is the most relevant document I can find,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference

The docs don't say  it explicitly, but requests are only performed when using the .set() or .on() methods